# Receive accelerometer and gyroscope signals from smartwatch using BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, accelerometer

I'm trying to develop an android app that should connect itself with a general smartwatch (miband, polar, etc.). In particular, I want to receive
accelerometer and gyroscope signals using Bluetooth.
I already read many articles about BLE but I didn't find any additional information about these signals. Does anyone know if it's possible to receive general signals like these? Is the solution feasible with any type of device?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturers of smartwatches generally don’t publish their bluetooth protocol. So even if it is theoretically possible, it is very hard to do it.

However, Some people reverse engineer the protocols and find ways to do it. Here is an article about how to get raw accelerometer and heartrate data from a MiBand device:

https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/how-i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-2-to-control-it-from-linux-a5bd2f36d3ad

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the SDKs from the manufacturers. And use the SDKs to make your APP compatible with the smartwatches with different brand. It's really a giant and trivial work because you are not sure whether the manufacturers are willing to cooperate with you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an [app](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=672707), that can connect to mi fit and offers additional tools for xiaomi bands. In the "Tools" section you can extract the accelerometer data, however there is no option for gyroscope

P.S. Sorry, the site is in Russian, hope you can figure it out ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33257672)